# Spring @Transactional not synchronized

Tags: java, spring, transactions

This is my code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}

@Service("service1")
public class UserService1 implements Runnable {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("*** Start Transaction 1 ***");
        User user = userRepository.findOne(1L);
        user.setName("user " + Math.random());
        System.out.println("Sleeping ...");
        try {Thread.sleep(10000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("Updating user in Transaction 1... ");
        userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println("*** Completed 1 ***");
    }
}

@Service("service2")
public class UserService2 implements Runnable {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("*** Start Transaction 2 ***");
        User user = userRepository.getOne(1L);
        user.setName("User_service2");
        userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println("*** Completed 2 ***");
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        Executor e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        e.execute((Runnable) context.getBean("service1"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        e.execute((Runnable) context.getBean("service2"));
    }
}
```

I have two services with same isolation level, both do an entity update. Second start after completely start of first (sleep for a 2 seconds). First one is a "slow" one.

Because of `isolation = SERIALIZABLE` I expect this will create a lock for whole user table while any of services executing it work:
In my case `service2` should wait until `service1` completes it work, but this does not happen.

Could somebody please clarify why it does not work? Maybe I missed something in description. 
Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

Added system output.

```
*** Start Transaction 1 ***
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.name as name2_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
Sleeping ...
*** Start Transaction 2 ***
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.name as name2_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
*** Completed 2 ***
Hibernate: update user set name=? where id=?
Updating user in Transaction 1... 
*** Completed 1 ***
Hibernate: update user set name=? where id=?
2016-07-16 11:47:29.267  WARN 15656 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001
2016-07-16 11:47:29.267 ERROR 15656 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

**UPDATE 2:**

DB: MySQL 5.6.25

Comment: can  you show your sysout ?

Comment: Added sout. Sorry, missed it while created a question.

Comment: The issue is due to one uses `findOne` the other `getOne`. The latter returns a proxy instead of actually accessing the database until you do some action on the object. Also serializable access depends on the database you are using how locks are handled or if it is even supported.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed both to findOne: still does not work as expected. Added Update 2 section with MySql version.